# How to define dataset as a daily timeseries dataset in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm currently working on an analysis of a dataset. The dataset looks like this: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjmKI.png)

I am slightly unsure about how to inform R that it is a daily timeseries dataset, with the dates defined in column A.

After informing R that it is a daily timeseries dataset, I am planing to do regressions on the dataset.

If anyone knows how to do this, then it would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards :)

Comment: You should make your example reproducible (instead of a screenshot) and provide some code of what you've tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lubridate https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/ part of the tidyverse.
I assume you have imported your dataframe into R, then select the column and covert to Date format using lubridate:

```
dmy(df$Date)
```